# Fees charging time in the process of Express Checkout

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I want to create a site that uses PayPal for charging users,
But I want the transaction to happen only after a manager verified the order

I thought of using the Express Checkout API and call the `DoExpressCheckout` api call only after I get the verification from the admin.

The question is - If I happen to cancel the transaction (because the admin decided that the order is not valid) - will I still be charged for PayPal fees despite the fact that the end user isn't charged? (The question refers to both the fixed fee and the percentage of the deal that is taken as a fee)

And also - Is it technically possible to do so? (cancel the transaction after I got the user's details and before I call `DoExpressCheckout`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use auth & capture. Call DoEC with action=auth; verify and/or whatever else you want to do; then capture funds. You are charged only on the capture. If you decide not to accept the transaction, call DoVoid to void it out.

Comment: Thanks, and for those who find this, this is the relevant article on PayPal's documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/authcapture/